# DC motor datasheet: dimensions

Tags: motor, dc-motor, datasheet, cad, mechanical-assembly

I have a PC280LG-302 DC motor, and I need to know the shaft length for this. In the [documentation](https://disti-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/testco-inc/files/datasheets/25271.pdf) they just wrote it as DIM."A" and total length as DIM."B". Can anybody understand this? Or is there something I am missing?

Here is the drawing of the motor model from the documentation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

DIM A and DIM B are going to be variable depending on the shaft length, this will depend on what model of motor/shaft you have. Since there is no information on the manufacturers website, you will need to contact them directly to find these dimensions

Answer (score 0):

The documentation should include a table with part numbers and the corresponding dimensions for "A" and "B".  If it doesn't, it's incomplete.